# zabbix : prob.... with defaults entries ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, zabbix, debian-buster

Zabbix sends me those annoying emails with body:

```
zabbix : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;
```

Now I do **not** have `sssd` installed, nor do I have `sss` word in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, like this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1086152/sudo-sending-annoying-alerts-issue-with-defaults-entries) would suggest.

What I do have re sudo + zabbix is `/etc/sudoers.d/zabbixsudoers`:

```
zabbix             ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/needrestart -b -r l *, /sbin/drbdadm
```

How can I turn those emails off?

Comment: So what are the Defaults entries you have set?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid these messages, when you remove Zabbix from the sudo list. Your Security Officer would have bad dreams when you give root access to a freeware program that doesn't need it.
How about monitoring all those root-only items?
You can have root check these with crontab. Root can report with zabbix_sender (sorry Security Officer) or write to a file and `chown zabbix:zabbix that_file`. The zabbix_sender can report one item or send a file with a batch of items to the zabbix server.